# Android Show Soft Keyboard When First Activity Starts?

Tags: java, android, keyboard, android-activity, show

I need to display the virtual keyboard when the application starts, but so far I've failed.

I use this code in method "OnCreate"to display the virtual keyboard

```
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(txtBuscar.getId(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

this code works fine on any screen at any time, but does not work when the "first" activity begins. Why?

I tried it when I start another activity and it works, but does not work when I start the "first"activity.

I tried to put this code in the events "OnCreate"and many more .... but it seems not work.

is there anyway to "force" to display the keyboard when I start the application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I Found the solution:

```
txtPassword.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager)
                getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                keyboard.showSoftInput(txtPassword, 0); 
            }
        },200);
```

Thanks !!!

Comment: Seems to work only in the portrait mode. When I switch to landscape mode the soft keyboard refuses to come on. I tried it both ways. Phone in landscape mode before the activity is launched and switching to landscape when the activity is shown. Any clues on how to proceed?

Comment: Great! Is it android bug? Trying run keyboard at onResume(), but first time not started without such delay

Answer (score 1):

onCreate will not be called if the activity is first brought from background. Have you tried put that code in onResume?

onCreate is called only when activity is first start or the activity is killed and user navigate to the activity again. So if the activity is still alive but in background, it will not call onCreate.

On the other hand, onResume will be called every time the activity comes to foreground (visible on screen) from background.

Here is link to activity life cycle if you are interested http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same issue, this method below helped me

```
public static void showKeyboard(Context context) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (imm != null) {
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
    }
}
```