# Keyboard doesn't show up when enter to activity in Android Pie (API-28)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-softkeyboard, android-9.0-pie

I want to pop up the device keyboard when I enter to Email Login screen.

I declared the `windowSoftInputMode` to `"stateVisible"` in the **AndroidManifest.xml** file:

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.EmailLoginActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"   
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" />
```

I have followed this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility).

**Results:**

On devices that run Android API up to 27, the keyboard is shown.

On devices that run the Android API 28, the keyboard is not shown.

Is it a bug in Android Pie?

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Seems in Android Pie (API 28), it is not setting request focus in `EditText` automatically.

**So you have to set the `requestFocus` of your `EditText` either programmatically or in the XML file.**

**your_layout.xml**

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_email"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```

**OR**

**your_activity.java**

```
findViewById(R.id.et_email).requestFocus();
```

Comment: If you are calling requestFocus() from onResume(),  you will need to delay the call see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227118/android-show-soft-keyboard-when-first-activity-starts

Answer (score 1):

I did have an issue with this as well for Android Pie. `.requestFocus()` didn't work for me.

**Solution for my problem:**

Make sure your `EditText` is actually visible. I used the `EditText` as a hidden field, and the keyboard only showed up after setting the width and height from `0` to `1dp`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use hidden EditText with 0dp width and height, it won't work on API 28 pie, I was able to make it work by setting dimensions to 1dp and all parts of widget to transparent.
This worked for me:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/hacked_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Comment: I have an EditText with the width and height set to wrap_content in an LinearLayout with the Visibility INVISIBLE for the LinearLayout. My EditText could not retrieve focus in Android Pie. I used this answer to set the width and height of my editText to 1dp, then it worked like a charm again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with me was in device keyboard settings.
Language and Input 
Default keyboard 
and change it to your device keyboard samsung in my case.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's nicely documented in [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility#ShowOnDemand):

```
fun showSoftKeyboard(view: View) {
    if (view.requestFocus()) {
        val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.EmailLoginActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"   
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" />
```

Hope this helps you