# Android default focus behavior in new API versions

Tags: java, android, layout, focus

I have a simple test app with a single `EditText`. When I run it on API 24 device, this EditText is focused by default after app starts. But when I run it on newer Android API versions (API 28, for example), I have no focused view after app starts.
Here is Java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

And here is layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:hint="hint"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is a piece of my build.gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.gmail.kapusta.yu.focustest"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

And, when I set targetSdkVersion to 26, I receive "old" behavior with EditText focused by default on API 28 device.

So, the questions are:

1. Why do we have such a behavior in different versions?
2. How can I get the "old" behavior with default focus on EditText on new devices when targetSdkVersion is 30 and maybe more (in future)?

I know that I can call requestFocus() in onResume(), for example, but it does not seem to be a good way.

Answer (score 2):

The official docs confirm that views are not implicitly focused since targetSdkVersion 28 https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#focus. So we have to do this explicitly as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950681/95313.